# How to check an EditText has focus?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to check an **EditText** has focus? is there any method `boolean hasFocus()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `hasFocus()` is there, inherited from [android.view.View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#hasFocus%28%29)

Another way to achieve this

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);

if(this.getCurrentFocus().getId() == et.getId()){
    // your view is in focus
}else{
    // not in the focus
}
```

Comment: also u can try ise view.getCurrentFocus()